# How to delete Wampserver in Windows 7

Tags: wampserver

I want to uninstall WAMP from Windows 7, but it does not appear in the Programs and Features list. Can I simply delete the files, or is there something else I also need to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the \wamp\ folder you should see a file called `unins000.exe`

Run that file and then manually delete the \wamp folder.